# Can you get presigned URLs using Perl Paws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Is it possible to get presigned URLs using Perl Paws?

I am trying to download objects from an S3 bucket to a local server and have not been successful yet. There is a method to use GetObject and read the body to a file but the Objects I am trying to receive are .gz files so they cannot be read via GetObject.

Any suggestions on alternatives are welcome.